# Removing empty rows and shifting remaining rows up in a range before copying and pasting another range

Tags: excel, vba

Still learning the ins and outs of VBA. I have two ranges: (A:E) and (F:J). They need to be condensed into a singular range. The first range has empty rows, which need to be deleted. After these rows are deleted, the remaining rows are shifted up. The second range is then copied and pasted underneath.

How would we fix the current issue with empty columns & cells?

```
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim firstRng As Range
    Dim secondRng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    
    'Setting worksheets and Ranges
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1 (5)")

    ' Define Range 1
    With ws
        Set firstRng = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp))
    End With
    
    ' Removing empty rows from firstRng and shifting up
    For i = firstRng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
      If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(firstRng.Rows(i)) = 0 Then
        firstRng.Rows(i).Delete Shift:=xlUp
      End If
    Next i
    
    ' Define Range 2
    With ws
        Set secondRng = Range(.Cells(1, 6), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp))
    End With
    
    ' Paste second range below first
    secondRng.Copy ws.Cells(firstRng.Rows.Count + 1, 1)
    secondRng.ClearContents
'

End Sub
```

Photos of the result.
[image: Before]

[image: After]

Comment: Instead of complications with managing ranges in actual data, I would suggest: 1.pick up both ranges in 2 separate arrays. 2. Skip blanks rows from the both arrays to a 3rd array. 3. Clear the output area and paste the de-blanked 3rd array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually simpler than you're trying to make it. This assumes that the last row in both ranges has a non-empty cell in the 5th column (columns E and J). It will fail if either of those cells is empty (the End-Up will not find the correct row in that case).

```
Sub RemoveRows()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim firstRng As Range
    Dim secondRng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    
    'Setting worksheets and Ranges
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    ' Define Range 1
    With ws
        Set firstRng = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp))
    End With
    
    ' Removing empty rows from firstRng and shifting up
    For i = firstRng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
      If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(firstRng.Rows(i)) = 0 Then
        firstRng.Rows(i).Delete Shift:=xlUp
      End If
    Next i
    
    ' Define Range 2
    With ws
        Set secondRng = Range(.Cells(1, 6), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp))
    End With
    
    ' Paste second range below first
    secondRng.Copy ws.Cells(firstRng.Rows.Count + 1, 1)
    secondRng.ClearContents
    
End Sub
```

#### Edit

Not sure what you mean by the loop never concludes. Nothing infinite here:

[image: Before and after screen shots]

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. What would you suggest to fix the subscript out of range error created by the Set ws line?

Comment: I'm guessing it's actually not on the ```Set ws``` line, unless your workbook doesn't have a Sheet1. That would generate the error. Assuming Sheet1 does exist, the statement ```Set firstRng = ws.Range("A:E")``` includes all rows in the worksheet in ```firstRng```. Following that with ```upperRow = firstRng.Rows.Count + lastUsedRow``` tries to go beyond the last row (unless ```lastUsedRow <= 0```). That's would also generate the "subscript out of range" error. I didn't bother to address that because it's just one of several issues in your code.

Comment: It does have a Sheet1. I know the current loop I used goes on indefinitely. That's what I'm trying to fix. With the find lastusedrow of Range 2, I intended on using that as a starting point for the first range loop. So how would I format this to achieve that ?

Comment: I recommend that you step through my code line by line (F8 in the VB editor). Think about what each statement is doing, and look at its effect on the worksheet. You'll learn more from that than from us trading comments here. It will show you how to find the starting point you're looking for. I'm not going to spend time addressing each error in the code you posted (it has several errors). That's not an efficient use of our time.

Comment: I'm not trying to be difficult, I'm actually trying to help. My code does everything you described in your question, so going through it (thoughtfully of course) should answer your questions. If the code works for you, please accept it as the answer. If it does not work, please let us know where it goes wrong so we can help fix it. Even if you want to fix your own code (a laudable exercise, and you'll learn from doing so), you should be able to find the answers in my post to make your own code work as desired.

Comment: My reputation has not increased enough to initiate a chat with you. I don't believe you are being difficult. I appreciate the help you have given me so far. One thing I've thought of with the delete row loop is storing of the rows in a data variable, which should prevent the endless loop issue. I'd like to hear your thoughts on the matter.

Comment: It seems like an increase in complexity. Ask yourself what you would expect to gain from such an increase. I'd argue that complexity in and of itself imposes costs, both in the initial coding and debugging, and in subsequent maintenance. I would want an offsetting benefit to make that increase worthwhile.